# What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '21.0.2'. qtcreator 5.12.12

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, qt-creator

:-1: error: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  **Could not determine java version from '21.0.2'.**
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

**(SDK Version: 12.0, NDK Version: 21.3.6528147)**

### Gradle 8.3

Build time:   2023-08-17 07:06:47 UTC
Revision:     8afbf24b469158b714b36e84c6f4d4976c86fcd5

Kotlin:       1.9.0
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
OS:           Linux 6.5.0-17-generic amd64

when i want to debug app on my android, there is this error

i install everything and nothing changed

Comment: i have linux ubuntu

Comment: Gradle 8.3 doesn't support Java 21. You need Gradle 8.5 or 8.6.

Comment: I installed gradle 8.6
Gradle 8.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2024-02-02 16:47:16 UTC
Revision:     d55c486870a0dc6f6278f53d21381396d0741c6e

Kotlin:       1.9.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
OS:           Linux 6.5.0-17-generic amd64
but error doesnt go away

Comment: i think make the project in android studio easier and faster, than that qt...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java SDK Version 21 requires a minimum of Gradle 8.4 for compiling Java classes via Gradle Refresh and requires Gradle 8.5 for running custom Gradle logic.

You can check the Gradle - Java compatibility matrix for all version requirements:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html